# How do I convey "As you all know"?

Tags: translation, words

Having been trying to write a "sakubun", I must say that I had some trouble to find a reliable translation for the phrase "as you all know" such as:

> **As you all know**, the education system in our country is not so good as it's claimed to be.
>
> **As known by all of you**, the education system in our country is not so good as it's claimed to be.

I'd appreciate if you translated the whole sentence; however, it's not really necessary.

よろしくおねがいします！

Comment: どうもありがとうございました→よろしくおねがいします

Comment: Note that `as you all know` in English as well as its Japanese counterpart is impolite and inaccurate. You can rarely be sure what all people know. If you use that expression without proof that it is true, you will be lying, and presupposing something about people's mind. A more appropriate expression is `as is widely known`, `周知のように`.

Comment: @sawa, it may not be 100% accurate 100% of the time, but "as you all know" is widely used and I wouldn't say that it's "impolite", but perhaps a little less formal than one could otherwise put it. For example, I could easily see Onur's first example sentence said at a conference on how to improve the country's education system, etc...

Comment: I disagree entirely that "as you all know" is impolite or inaccurate in English. It's used constantly in academic settings to bring up a supporting point that is self-evident or reflects a common assumption. There is a very minor point that it is appropriate for a lecture or talk from an expert. But, frankly, someone who objected to that would be dismissed as hypersensitive. English does NOT have the same guideline as Japanese, that removing the specifics from a phrase tends to make it more polite.

Comment: @jkerian I rather think that whomever considers that these objections as hypersensitive is ignorant. They do not qualify to do a serious academic study. And there is no difference between English and Japanese regarding that. And you seem to be missing the point. It is not about specifics. It is about stepping into other people's mind and making (false) assumptions about it.

Comment: @jkerian It depends on context. It's also used frequently in political settings to dismiss the opposing opinion as trivial, in which case it can be (and is often) offensive to the opposing party.  The example provided by the OP sounds like an opinion rather than an academic statement backed by facts.  Then again, the English site is a better place to discuss English usage.

Comment: @Troyen: I thought of that as well, but it's not actually relevent. Any linguistic mechanism for stating a fact *can* be used as an insult (and probably will be by a politician). Sawa's rather expansive claim is that the construction itself, even about things which the audience would actually know, is inappropriate for a formal occasion. This simply isn't true. (please note: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22as+you+all+know%22). This actually is a HUGE difference between Japanese and English. By and large, English speakers simply aren't sensitive to constructions like this.

Comment: @sawa, would you say that is YOUR opinion, or a general opinion among Japanese? If the latter, I'd be interested in sources. Personally, I don't think the phrase is impolite. I think it carries the nuance of "sorry for wasting your time with trivialities, I just mention this to create a frame of reference". But sure, depending on the situation, it *could* be used as an insult.

Answer (score 10):

What you're looking for should be `ご存じの通り` or `ご承知の通り`

> ご存じの通り、我が国の教育制度は、（+実際には）、言われているほど（or 言われるほど）良いものではありません。

Comment: What about 言われたように良くない

Comment: 「ご存じの通り（orご存じのように）、我が国の教育制度'は'、（+'実際には'）、言われている'ほど'（or言われるほど）良いもの'では'ありません。」・・・かな～

Comment: @Flaw Sorry, I removed the down vote, since you're actually answering the main question correctly. You could improve by translating the rest of the sentence correctly, as Chocolate did.

Comment: わが国の教育制度が事実はあまり良くない part does not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Supplement:  You also could use `知っている通り（に）` toward a more familiar crowd.

Comment: Hmm...「知っている通りに」・・・？？Well I might say 「知ってると思うけど/知ってるでしょうけど」to friends (but never in a conference)

Comment: It appears that the vast majority of the Google results for "知っている通りに" are used to mean "[verb] as [I] know how", e.g. "僕は知っている通りに書いた。" 


There are some examples of 知ってる通りに in the sense of "As [you] know, [some statement of fact]", but the trailing に sounds funny to me. Better to replace the に with a comma or verbal pause: "皆さんが知ってる通り、私は来月退職します。"

Comment: Also "知っている通り、" has the sense that the known fact is an important development/revelation that the audience has recently learned about, rather than a piece of general knowledge. Like in a press conference, when someone would say "Folks, as you are all aware, at 2pm yesterday our forces attacked..."

Comment: @PaulRichter san, Oooh I see, then in that case I'd rather say '知っての通り' than '知っている通り'.