# Can I use [自称]{じしょう}ほど for things other than namesake?

Tags: usage

> デス・クリムゾンはメーカーロゴ[画面]{がめん}[以外]{いがい}[自称]{じしょう}ほど[迫力]{はくりょく}がない。
>
> Other than its maker logo screen, Death Crimson is not as menacing as its namesake.

As with the sentence above, I can use 自称 for referring to namesake.

In [another question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4408/how-do-i-convey-as-you-all-know), the phrase `as it's claimed to be` is suggested to be translated to `言われているほど`. Can I use 自称 here instead? Like

> 我が国の教育制度は自称のほど良くない

Comment: Does 'namesake' have a meaning I don't know about? According to http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/namesake there are two meanings, and I cannot get either one to fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, I do not think that the use of 自称 in the first sentence is correct.  [自称](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E8%87%AA%E7%A7%B0&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=108389700000) means how someone refers to him/herself (regardless of how others refer to him/her).  For example, 自称音楽家 means a self-styled musician.  (This example was taken form [New Century Japanese-English Dictionary](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E8%87%AA%E7%A7%B0&dtype=3&dname=2ss&stype=0).)  It is not really about a name, but about a self-claimed occupation or some other attribute of a person.  I would say something like 名前から期待するほど instead of 自称ほど in the first sentence.

The use of 自称 in the second example is incorrect because 我が国の教育制度 (the education system in our country) does not refer to itself as something good.

Comment: You're right; I think the correct one was 自称+名詞+ほど. I've confused the usage. And even if the 名詞 is to be omitted, there must be a claim/self-styling previously, to which this 自称 refers to, and seems to always be followed with modifier+ものはない。

Comment: @syockit: 自称 is not always used as a prefix to a noun (as you correctly suspected).  自称ほど may make sense in certain context, although the best example I managed to come up with sounds still awkward: 彼は音楽家を自称しているが、自称ほど音楽のことを知っているわけではない。  (音楽家を名乗るほど sounds much more natural than 自称ほど in this sentence.)  The reason the two sentences are incorrect is because of the meaning, not the grammatical usage.

Comment: @syockit: In addition, the use of ない is related to ほど; AほどBない is a common pattern which means “not as B as A.”